# PHP Check Session if one has privilege

Tags: php, session, rights

I'm working on a MySQL Query to create a product in the database but I'm getting an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, fprice, inkoop, image, author, html) VALUES('1', 'bronze 5 - bronze 4', '1' at line 1

I have Googled it but can't find any problem in my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $shopid1 = $_POST['productid'];
    $prodname1 = $_POST['productname'];
    $desc1 = $_POST['desc'];
    $fprice1 = $_POST['fprice'];
    $price1 = $_POST['price'];
    $inkoop1 = $_POST['inkoop'];
    $image1 = $_POST['image'];
    $qty1 = $_POST['qty'];
    $html1 = $_POST['html'];
    $author1 = $_SESSION['name'];



        mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(shopid, name, qty, price, desc, fprice, inkoop, image, author, html) VALUES('$shopid1', '$prodname1', '$qty1', '$price1', '$desc1', '$fprice1', '$inkoop1', '$image1', '$author1', '$html1')", $conn)
            or die(mysql_error());  
        Header("Location: products.php");

} else {

}


?>
```

Hope someone can diagnose my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is reserved keyword. Try with -

```
INSERT INTO products(shopid, name, qty, price, `desc`,.....
```

Or rename it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a keyword and it can be either used using backticks or rename it in the database (if possible). Try as below :

```
INSERT INTO products
(shopid, name, qty, price, `desc`, fprice, inkoop, image, author, html)
VALUES
('$shopid1', '$prodname1', '$qty1', '$price1', '$desc1', '$fprice1', '$inkoop1', '$image1', '$author1', '$html1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the `keyword` **(desc)** in your query

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $shopid1 = $_POST['productid'];
    $prodname1 = $_POST['productname'];
    $desc1 = $_POST['desc'];
    $fprice1 = $_POST['fprice'];
    $price1 = $_POST['price'];
    $inkoop1 = $_POST['inkoop'];
    $image1 = $_POST['image'];
    $qty1 = $_POST['qty'];
    $html1 = $_POST['html'];
    $author1 = $_SESSION['name'];



        mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(shopid, name, qty, price, `desc`, fprice, inkoop, image, author, html) VALUES('$shopid1', '$prodname1', '$qty1', '$price1', '$desc1', '$fprice1', '$inkoop1', '$image1', '$author1', '$html1')", $conn)
            or die(mysql_error());  
        Header("Location: products.php");

} else {

}


?>
```

You can also checkout the reserved key words so that you don't make another mistake next time [MYSQL Reserved Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)